# asynchronous loading causes issue with tagsinput plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-tags-input

I am using bootstrap `tagsinput` plugin with `angularJS`.

To activate `tagsinput` machinery, it is simply required to add some `data-role` attributes

```
<input type="text" placeholder="add a tag" data-role="tagsinput">
```

which generate on the fly some html code. This works well. When I wrap this input inside this

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <input type="text" placeholder="add a tag" data-role="tagsinput">
```

the `AngularJS` part of the code works well. But when I wrap the input as so, the `tagsinput` plugin does not work anymore. After some testing, I am sure that the problem is related to the fact the page is rendered when the `todos` are fetched from the server. This asynchronous loading is for sure the issue because when the page is loaded and when I create some new `todo` with an data-roled `input`, the latter works well. So how can I deal with this loading. I hope I was clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So suppose you marked your inputs with `class="myClass"`, then do the following

delete data-role="tagsinput" to have some simple

```
<input type="text" placeholder="add a tag">
```

and then use in your angular code

```
$(document).find(".myClass").each(
              function(){$(this).tagsinput({});}
          );
```

this should do the job